# Toolkit MVVM AsyncRelayCommand.IsRunning PropertyChanged

Tags: windows-community-toolkit

I would like to have a single "IsLoading" ViewModel property exposed to my View. I would like this property depend on two other properties: AsyncRelayCommand(Loading1).IsRunning and AsyncRelayCommand(Loading2).IsRunning

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Is it possible to add handler for AsyncRelayCommand.PropertyChanged for
IsRunningChangedEventArgs?

Is there maybe some kind of attribute **[AlsoNotify...]**

```
[ICommand]
[AlsoNotifyIsRunningFor(nameof("IsLoading"))]
private Task LoadAsync()
```